# Is this a valid proof of "a, b are rational, b ≠ 0, r is irrational, then a + br is irrational"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

**Theorem:** If a and b are rational numbers, b ≠ 0, and r is an irrational number, then a + br is irrational.

**Proof:** Assume that if a and b are rational numbers, b ≠ 0, and r is an irrational number, then a + br is rational.

By the definition of rational, we can substitute a and b with fractions where p, q, m, n are particular but arbitrary integers.

```
    a = p/q   b = m/n

    a + br = p/q + (m/n)r/1

           = p/q + mr/n

           = (pn + qmr) / qn
```

Since r is irrational, we know that both the numerator and the denominator cannot be rational numbers, which implies a + br is irrational, which contradicts the fact that a + br is rational.  This contradiction shows the supposition is false, therefore the theorem is true.

Comment: $(m/n)r\neq mr/nr$ if $m,r\neq 0$ and $(\sqrt{2}/3\sqrt{2})=1/3$ even if the numerator and denominator are irrationals. Let's try this. Suppose that $a+br=q$ where $q$ is rational.  You have \begin{align*} a+br &= q\\ br&=q-a\\\end{align*}

Comment: Your setup is fine, but the concluding argument is not convincing.  Try solving for $r$ instead.

Comment: I believe r = (q - a) / b, which would make r a rational number (a contradiction), since it is the quotient of two rational numbers.  Does that prove the proposition?

Comment: Yes, you can also make it more explicit by expanding it to a ratio of two integers.

Comment: The numerator is in the form "c+dr" where c and d are rational and r is irrational. How did you deduce that the numerator is irrational, without assuming the thing you're trying to prove?

Answer (score 1):

" $$ a + br =...= (pn + qmr) / qn $$
...
Since r is irrational, we know that both the numerator and the denominator cannot be rational numbers.

"

I think your conclusion is illogical / not deductive.

Your assumption was:

"Assume that if a and b are rational numbers, b ≠ 0, and r is an irrational number, then a + br is rational."

The numerator, $pn + qmr, $ is in the form $c+dr$ where $c$ and $d$ are rational and $r$ is irrational. How did you deduce that the numerator, $pn + qmr, $ is irrational, without assuming the thing you're trying to prove?

In fact, your assumption implies that the numerator $is$ rational.

You were on the right track in your proof until this part:

$a + br = p/q + (m/n)r/1$

I think you got "caught up in the maths" and forgot about the logical reasoning of the proof.

I would slightly modify the first line of your proof, which I assume you intended to be a proof by contradiction:

Proof: Assume that if a and b are rational numbers, b ≠ 0, and r is an irrational number, $and \ that \ $ a + br is rational. (Now your goal is to prove that some sort of contradiction will arise.)

By the definition of rational, we can substitute a and b with fractions where p, q, m, n are particular but arbitrary integers. (this bit is fine)

Your assumption assumed $a+br \ $ is rational, so now you should write:

$a + br = p/q$

and take it from there. Remember your goal now is to get a contradiction based on the fact that r is irrational and the rest of the numbers are rational.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is,since $b\neq 0$ and $b$ is rational we show
first $br$ must be irrational.

This is done by Contradiction

Suppose $br$ is rational ,then since $\frac{1}{b}$ is rational, the product $\frac{1}{b}(br)=r$ is rational.(Products of rational numbers are rational)

But this is a contradiction because by
Hypothesis $r$  is irrational.

Hence $br$ has to be irrational
(First step proved)

Remains to show that since br is irrational as we have shown already that also the sum
a+br is irrational.

If a is zero we have nothing more to show.

Otherwise we argue again by Contradiction and assume $a+br$ to be rational

Since $-a$ is rational(because a is rational) it follows that $-a+(a+br)=br$ is rational
(sums of rational numbers are rational),which contradicts the irrationality of $br$ shown in the first step.

Hence $a+br$ must be irrational

(Second step proved)

q.e.d